# Как правильно сверстать страницу для разных разрешений экрана?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Есть макет, по которому делается верстка. Нужно, чтобы страница отображалась во весь экран на разных разрешениях и разных мониторах (у каждого человека свой монитор: у кого-то большой, у кого-то маленький). Так вот, чтобы отображалось на всех мониторах и во весь экран, я просто взял картинки с макета (в ширину примерно 1300 px), где по бокам только фон, основная информация посередине. Вот и приходится заниматься всякой ерундой: подвигать всё влево на 50%, чтобы фон занимал только край монитора, а не половину: но при сворачивании окна все блоки уходят за экран и их не видно. Вобщем понимаю, что делаю что то не так....
Как правильно верстать макеты и как предусмотреть дизайн и для больших и для маленьких экранов?

Comment: Что-то ничего я не понял, зачем что куда двигать... Если блок контента посередина - так сделайте ему margin: 0 auto; и всё. А фон - пусть фоном и остаётся, для body его задайте.  
Я правильно Вас понял? Или в чем проблема?

Comment: Есть фон в хэдэре, который нужно сместить влево (отцентрировать), чтобы отображалась страница на весь экран на различных мониторах. Вопрос: как центрировать такой блок с фоном? "margin: auto" не отцентрирует, т.к. здесь скорее нужно "отрезать" кусок хэдэра слева и только затем поместить к краю экрана. А на бОльшем экране хэдэр не обрезается а остается таким как есть

Comment: Сместить влево(отцентрировать) - вы ничего не путаете? Получается какая-то ерунда! Покажите дизайн, хотя бы кусок, а то я никакне могу понять, что Вы хотите... %)

Comment: Вообще, я хочу понять как мне правильно делать дизайн и верстать макеты таким образом, чтобы страница отображалась во весь экран на всех мониторах (ну или почти на всех)

Comment: Угу - динамически вычеслять размеры экрана, тестить размеры шрифтов блоков для каждого из разрешений и писать много JS быдлокода, если вы готовы - вперед...<br>
Чисто css'ом написать чтобы все отлично отображалось как на 800x600 так и на 1200*1900 нельзя по определению<br>
По сабжу - если ТЗ соблюдено страница разверстана правильно xD

Comment: А если я дизайнер, то какую ширину выбирать ? )

Answer (score 1):

Есть 2 типа верстки: резиновая и фиксированная. Иногда их совмещают и получают гибридную.

**Резиновая верстка** создается по принципу "укажи свойства селектора в процентах". Можно сделать вывод, что сайт, сверстанный с использованием резиновой верстки будет автоматически менять размер под размер экрана каждого пользователя. На самом деле этот тип верстки имеет много подводных камней(потеря качества изображений при растягивании/сжатии; проблемы с размерами шрифтов, даже если их размерность указана в %; неожиданное или нерациональное отображение сайта в очень больших или слишком маленьких клиентах и тп.) и трудностей в реализации. Поэтому его относительно редко используют.

**Фиксированная верстка** предполагает указание свойств селекторов(размеры, отступы, размеры шрифта и тп.) в абсолютных величинах. То есть кол. блоков, которые будут тянуться - минимальное. Главные недостатки: полосы прокрутки в маленьких окнах браузера и пустующее пространство в больших.

**Гибридная верстка** включает в себя все лучшее из двух вышеуказанных. Как правило(все зависит от верстальщика), сайт тянется только в определенных границах [А1хБ1; А3хБ2], а за их пределами верстка становиться фиксированной.

***P.S.1:** Разумеется, не стоит думать, что при резиновой верстке верстальщик должен все имеющиеся величины отображать в процентной размерности, а при фиксированной - в абсолютной. Порой это не нужно или даже невозможно.

**P.S.2:** Иногда может понадобиться сделать несколько версток и выдавать одну из них в зависимости от ситуации. Например при разработке сайта, который должен одинаково отображаться на ПК и моб. устройствах.

**P.S3:** Рекомендую почитать [этот](http://demiart.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=44057) урок. А вообще, полазьте на указанном форуме, там довольно много полезных тем.*

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ! Очень полезная информация!

Answer (score 0):

если я правильно понял, то вам нужно статический блок с контентом в центре, и большая фоновая картинка которая будет отцентрированно.

приведу скелет для данной задачи:

```
<div class="page" style="background:url(images/нашакартинка.jpg) center top no-repeat">
    <div class="content" style="width:1000px;margin 0 auto;">контент</div> 
</div>
```

-где background:url(images/нашакартинка.jpg) center top no-repeat - одна большая картинка, если нужен повторяющийся фон  то надо ставить repeat-x (по горизонтали)
-width:1000px; - ширина блока контента
-margin 0 auto; - отцентрировает блок контента

так же фон может быть добавлен к body или html, если есть такая нужда.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я бы наверное тоже так ответил, но вопрос немного другой (извините, что непонятно выражаюсь). Мне нужна такая верстка, при которой хэдэр не будет тянуться и не будет сужаться, а останется неизменным на любом экране, а контент посередине будет менять положение (он должен быть посередине, и для этого как я понимаю надо ставить margin: 0 auto).

Comment: было бы круто если Вы бы показали шаблон, в 2-ух вариантах при разных разрешений потому что вопрос и вправду непонятен.
Возможно вам нужно задать width хэдера в процентах, а контент как уже говорилось margin:0 auto;

Comment: Первоначальный вопрос примерно такой: есть очень широкая картинка. Как ее сверстать, чтобы все отображалось корректно для всех экранов?

Теперь уже другой вопрос: какую ширину страницы задать при создании веб-страницы? )

Comment: делайте фон на сколько угодно. главное если уменьшать картинку-фона при помощи обрезания по бокам, то что бы фон оставался красивым.
а ширину блока в котором собственно сайт,  сделайте на 1000px. это стандарт на данный момент.

Comment: Вот тут и возникает такой важный момент: а если экран на 1200 px, а хэдэр на 1000 px, то как тогда делать?

Comment: отцентрируете.
а лучше, скиньте скрин (2 скрина под разные разрешения)
и тогда смогу помочь. В противном случае, больше ничем не могу помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ: нужно написать в css:

```
#header {width: 100%; background-position: center top;}
```

Фон белый, поэтому центрирую только хэдэр.